# How to pass babel options to @babel/register from command like require in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I have a script like `"start": "node -r @babel/register ./src/start.js"` and I want to pass in the `rootMode` option to `@babel/register` to have it find my config file. If I were requireing `@babel/register` in a file. I could do `require('@babel/register')({rootMode: 'upward'})`. However I don't want to have an entrypoint script to each file like this.

Is there a way to pass options to babel register when requiring in command line node?

Answer (score 2):

Just create `register.js` file like a

```
//register.js
require('@babel/register')({rootMode: 'upward'})
```

and then use script `"start": "node -r ./register.js ./src/start.js"`